# Covertir byte a imagen y mostrar en tabla

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-core

quiero mostrar una imagen que fue guardada en mi base de datos como byte a una tabla, de modo que la imagen se pueda descargar

[image: como ejemplo]

Este es el controlador de mi vista para poder hacer el registro de la imagen

```
public ActionResult Actas(FotosActa fotosActa)
{
            
        MetodosDB metodosDB = new MetodosDB(); //Aqui creo el objeto donde tengo mi metodo
        byte[] numArray1 = (byte[])null;
        if (fotosActa.imagen != null)
        {
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fotosActa.imagen.OpenReadStream())) //aqui convierto la imagen a byte
            {
             numArray1 = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fotosActa.imagen.Length);
             fotosActa.imagenExtension = fotosActa.imagen.ContentType;
             }
        }


            
        fotosActa.imagenByte = numArray1;
            
        if (metodosDB.GuardarImg(fotosActa))
        {
           ViewBag.ResultadoBueno = "Se ha ingresado correctamente";
        }
        return (ActionResult)this.View();
}
```

Este ese el metodo, donde llamo el procedimiento almacenado donde hace el proceso de registrar los datos

```
public bool GuardarImg(FotosActa fotosActa)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Conectar())
                {
                    this.com = new SqlCommand("Registrar_FotoActa", this.cadena);
                    this.com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    if (fotosActa.imagenByte != null)
                    {
                        this.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagen", (object)fotosActa.imagenByte);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@imagen", SqlDbType.Image);
                        sqlParameter.Value = (object)DBNull.Value;
                        this.com.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
                    }
                    this.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagenExtension", string.IsNullOrEmpty(fotosActa.imagenExtension) ? (object)"" : (object)fotosActa.imagenExtension);
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
          
        }
```

No se como pasar el byte a imagen y poder mostrarlo en la pantalla en una tabla, he estado investigando, pero n he visto nada claro para asp.net core 6

Comment: A que te refieres a mostrarlo en pantalla en una tabla?

Comment: En principio solo tienes que hacer el proceso inverso y 'asociarlo' al control que quiera mostrarlo.

Comment: Piensa que lo que has guardado es el contenido de un fichero imagen(p.e jpg) y si lo guardas en un archivo .jpg y lo abres veras la imagen. No digo que esa sea la solución, no es necesario.

Comment: @Francisco es como el ejemplo que mostre al principio, esa imagen, que sea como un link y al solo precionar descargue la imagen

Answer (score 0):

**Para crear una imagen en memoria de un chorro de bytes**:

```
   Byte[] byteBLOBData;
            byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(datosBasedatos);
            MemoryStream imagen = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);
```

Enviarla como respuesta a una solicitud:

```
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.Clear();
    return imagen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
[HttpGet("GetImagen/{Id}")]
public async Task<FileResult> GetImagen(int id)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = // aqui el array de bytes
    return File(fileBytes, "image/png","nombre.png"); //3er argumento es opcional
}
```

o esto

```
[HttpGet("GetImagen/{Id}")]
public async Task<FileResult> GetImagen(int id)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = // aqui el array de bytes
    var ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");
}
```

Y luego desde el HTML haces

```
<img src="~/GetImagen/@Model.Id" />
```

Obviamente Model.Id representa el id de la base de datos de tu imagen, en tu caso tienes que poner lo que sea acorde a tu proyecto